# Apex TRY ... CATCH ... FINALLY Syntax

Tags: apex, trigger, data, error

I have gone through at least 10 sites explaining the use of this.  What I **cannot ascertain** is **if I simply want to try something** and if it fails, **go on** (don't need to do anything with the error).  I have some fields where each one exists "per product" as needed (or not).  At the top of the routine, I would like to do a simplistic:

```
try{ accObj.put('PB_Stage_UTP_OnDemand__c','testtttttt'); } catch( Exception exx ){ }
```

Is this "acceptable"?  It tests fine.  **Do I HAVE to do anything with the Exception result?**

Comment: I'd log the exception in a system.debug log. Also ideally I'd catch a sub class of exception eg dmlexception rather than top level exception lest an undesirable scenario causes the exception eg accObj being Null would cause a NullPointerException which you may or may not want to ignore

Comment: "Per product" suggests some loop. Pity sObjects can't implement an interface `hasFieldXYZ` ;) Describe() call on each sounds like an overkill... But from "philosophical" point of view are you 100% sure it's ok to "just try" without checking if field exists and `isUpdateable()` by current user? I'd prefer some runtime checks along lines `instanceOf` etc to be honest.

Comment: (related to other posts about my Piggyback trigger)  The routine goes though "all Opps for 1 account that have Product_List__c = [val]" and summarizes them onto the Account.  The trigger itself is great because it started with temp vars all NULL and populates them from scratch every time (so it's Self cleaning).  I'm trying to create a mechanism that starts with all null ON THE ACCOUNT where it writes as well.  SOME Product_List__c entries have fields a,b,c,d,e... some have a,c,e... some have a,e... I just want to blanket null "[product]_a__c" (a,b,c,d,e) for the product being checked.

Comment: You could create a custom setting to map product fields to account fields based on product type.

Comment: (continued)  The alternative (not the END of the world...) is that I would have to add IF logic to each set of fields (there is about 20, not just a,b,c,d,e) BEFORE I have access to the vars that tell me which fields WOULD be written to.  :-P   I'm trying to get around my "after delete" issue by starting with the fields EMPTY every time it fires (which is how the Temp Variables IN THE TRIGGER start every time ANYWAY).  Because when a record is deleted, the trigger is bypassing logic including WRITING to the Account, it is not writing those "still NULL" temp variables.  I have to separately.

Comment: Why can't you nullify all fields on Acc to start with? Any special reason you need the "temp variables in the trigger"? Make 1 round through trigger.old / trigger.new, collect Ids of Accounts, fetch them & nullify, make second "calculating" loop... https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+error+resume+next%22+is+evil

Comment: Heh.  I agree with the Google search result you posted.  ;-)  That is why I posted the question in the first place.  I was looking for "approval" from someone telling me "it's okay, do JUST THAT, don't worry about it" (rofl).   You both are giving me things to think about.  This monsterous (to me) trigger is a work of Love for over 2 years now and works very well overall.. just has this hole I need to patch that leaves abandoned data.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my needs and only low-level developer knowledge to date (plus timelines involved), I'm using a solution provided [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/simple-to-use-if-field-exists-logic):

```
Set<String> objectFields = Schema.SObjectType.My_Object__c.fields.getMap().keySet();
if(objectFields.contains(fieldName)) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This question has already been marked correct, but for anyone who come along after this: Never use a try-catch block to control logic flow. Always use some type of `if-else` construct. Exception handling is for dealing with problems, or things that you don't expect.