# What are the best practices for Triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice

**My requirements** are:

1. Upon creation of Accounts there is a trigger that creates a contact with specific record type `Organization Donor Proxy`
2. I wanted to create another trigger on Account after **Insert/Update** that will update a field `Aaron_Contact_id__c` with the `Aaron_Account_id__c`

**Trigger**

```
trigger Account_UpdateDonorProxyTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

    Contact[] dpContact = new list<Contact>();        // donor proxy contact

    try{
        Map<id, account> acctMap = Trigger.newmap;
        //for (Account acct : trigger.new){
        System.debug('account ids >>> :' + acctMap.keyset());        
        // Get all the contacts against each AccountId
        for (Contact cnt: [SELECT contact.id, contact.accountid, contact.name, contact.Aaron_Contact_Id__c, contact.RecordType.Name
                           FROM Contact
                           WHERE Contact.accountid IN: acctMap.keyset() ]){ 
            System.debug('Contact record type <<< :' + cnt.RecordType.Name);
            if(cnt.RecordType.Name == 'Organization Donor Proxy'){

                cnt.Aaron_Contact_ID__c = acctMap.get(cnt.accountid).Aaron_Account_ID__c;
                dpContact.add(cnt);

            }
        }       // end of for loop
        //}            
        update dpContact;
    }
    catch (exception ex){
        System.Debug('stack trace string:::' + ex.getStackTraceString() );
    }

}
```

**Question**
Does this trigger comply with the apex best practices? Am I missing something or anything that can be improved? What are the best practices and pitfalls in triggers anyways.

Comment: I realize this question has an accepted answer, but I thought I'd point out that you don't need a trigger.  What you are trying to accomplish can be done with Process Builder.

Comment: @DougB: True that but (a) this question was posted when Process builder was not out. (b) I, rather needed to know the whether my code is in compliance with the best practices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After searching here and there and writing few triggers myself, I have come up with the following:

1. Follow proper [naming conventions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/890/what-is-a-good-set-of-naming-conventions-to-use-when-developing-on-the-force-com) to make your code more logical and readable.
2. Write one-trigger per object.

   - Use trigger [context-variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) to identify specific event and performs tasks accordingly.
3. Logic-less triggers

   - Now, debugging in apex is itself serious pain, adding whole lot of logic in trigger and debugging it is... well you can guess. So, break your trigger logic in to trigger-handler classes.
4. Context-Specific Handler Methods

   - Using specific methods in your trigger-handler-class to keep your code clean and scalable.
5. Use a [framework](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework).

   - A framework! Why? It will make your code conform to the best practices, better testing, scalability and cleaner.
6. Keep the salesforce [order-of-execution](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) of events in mind (they will come in handy).
7. Understand when to use [before-trigger and when to user after-trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm).
8. Write trigger logic to support [bulk operations](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm).
9. Triggers can't contain test methods. So, its unit tests must be saved in a separate file.
10. Use **custom settings** to turn the trigger `On/Off`.

    - Once deployed, any changes or making a trigger `Active/Inactive`, you would need to make the changes on **sandbox** and then push it from their using changeset or IDE. Using custom settings to make a decision on the trigger will make life easy.

Helpful links:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices
http://www.iterativelogic.com/salesforce-apex-trigger-best-practices/
http://krishhari.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/an-architecture-framework-to-handle-triggers-in-the-force-com-platform

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/apex-best-practices-15-apex-commandments.html
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

Answer (score 2):

If the trigger is working properly, then for the best practices

1)  Never use a try-catch block to control logic flow. Always use some type of if-else construct. Exception handling is for dealing with problems, or things that you don't expect.

Source : [[Apex TRY ... CATCH ... FINALLY Syntax](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10600/apex-try-catch-finally-syntax][1])

2) Instead of writing multiple Triggers on the same object, it is best practice to create one trigger and handle all the contexts in the Handler Classes.

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers

Comment: +1 - I really like to second point. I guess I'm pretty much in-compliance with the first point :)