# SOQL Query in Trigger

Tags: community

Im writing a Trigger as follows on the Order object.

```
 List<Order> Ords = Trigger.New;

     for(Order O : Ords)
    {

         System.debug(':::::::::::O.TotalAmount '+O.TotalAmount);

        System.debug(':::::::::::O.Account.Name '+O.Account.Name);

       Account Act = [select Name from Account WHERE Name =: O.Account.Name];

---------------

}
```

I get an error when trying to insert Order record. Its returning NULL value for O.Account.Name.While it recognizes O.TotalAmount which is another field in Order Object.

In Order, Account is a lookup field. How to refer to the Account Name in Order object as part of above SOQL query.

Thanks,
Priya

How to change the following code according to Governor Limits.Please help.

```
Trigger OrderRollUpTrigger on Order (After Insert, After Update) {
    List<Order> Ords = Trigger.New;

    System.debug(':::::::::::AFT List ');

    for(Order O : Ords)
    {
       Account Act = [select Name from Account WHERE ID=: O.AccountID];

        AggregateResult AggRes = [select SUM(TotalAmount)TotAmt from Order WHERE Account.Name =: Act.Name];

        Act.CQ_Rollup_Order_Amount__c    =     Double.valueOf(AggRes.get('TotAmt'));

        Database.Update(Act);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your entire trigger `code`.

Comment: plz check out @Dominic's suggestions and also check this [post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58454/what-are-the-best-practices-for-triggers/60355#60355) for trigger guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

In a trigger, all the fields of the trigger object are available and populated, but fields on related objects are not.

So you can use `Order.Name` and `Order.AccountId` but not `Order.Account.Name`. Which is fine because you can find a Account from its Id more reliably than by its name.

By the way, it's very bad practise to perform queries in loops in a trigger. The trigger might run for 200 objects at a time, and then you would break the 100 SOQLs limit on an execution.

There is a good answer on trigger bulkification (managing the fact that the trigger will potentially run for up to 200 records at a time) [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices/47490#47490).

Comment: Right on but her error specification is related to `Insert`.

Comment: @mahmoodbutt why but?

Comment: Oops! I missed that part `Its returning NULL value for O.Account.Name.` from the question. :-|

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton Dominic. Its working and does update the reqd field in Account object.

This is the code.

How should I change it to avoid "100 SOQLs limit " issue you have mentioned.

Thanks,
Priya

Trigger OrderRollUpTrigger on Order (After Insert, After Update) {
    List Ords = Trigger.New;

```
System.debug(':::::::::::AFT List ');

for(Order O : Ords)
{


   Account Act = [select Name from Account WHERE ID=: O.AccountID];

    AggregateResult AggRes = [select SUM(TotalAmount)TotAmt from Order WHERE Account.Name =: Act.Name];

    Act.CQ_Rollup_Order_Amount__c    =     Double.valueOf(AggRes.get('TotAmt'));

    Database.Update(Act);


}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange Priya. I'm glad I could help you. The format of SSE is Question and Answer. If you want to expand on your question, then please edit the original question. What you've posted here isn't an answer, it's more question. And if you want to thank someone who has helped you, the best way to do it is by upvoting and/or accepting their answer. This helps Salesforce Stack Exchange to grow into a repository of useful questions and answers, for future users to find.